# Repeating Alarmmanager to stop at quite/night hours

Tags: android

I have an alarmmanager set to fire every 3 hours a day and its working fine. Now my problem is i dont want alarmmanager to fire at night hours i.e from 9pm to 9am on next day.

My code:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
   long interval = 3*60*60*1000;
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

and to stop this alarmmanager repeating, i used this snippet to stop manually.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Now how do i check if the time is in night hours or at day hours?

Comment: Well, if you have non-regular repeating alarm, you cannot use `setRepeating()`. Instead, you have to always calculate what time the alarm should go off, check whether it is within 9pm-9am, and use `setExact()`.

Comment: setExact() is only for KITKAT OS or higher, so what about the rest or lower version??

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was `set()`. It should be the same as `setExact()` for older version.

Comment: @AndrewT. if i change my code like this will it fire at every 3 hrs. alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval, pendingIntent);